# filter certain TR based on checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

Please help me as I am still trying to grasp the jQuery coding. I have this data and would like to filter it based on users' check box selection as the html code below.

.All rows are displayed when nothing is checked.

.All rows are displayed when all check boxes checked

.Only rows that meet selected criteria are displayed. For example,

a. When 2GB checked, only 2GB rows displayed.

b. When Shipping and 2GB checked, only Memory3 is displayed

```
<input type="checkbox" >1GB<br/>
<input type="checkbox" >2GB<br/>
<input type="checkbox" >4GB<br/>
<input type="checkbox" >1000MHz<br/>
<input type="checkbox" >1333MHz<br/>
<input type="checkbox" >Discontinued<br/>
<input type="checkbox" >Shipping<br/>
<br /><br />

<table class="someclass" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="bla">
<caption>bla bla</caption>
<thead>
    <tr id="ProductID">
        <th>Product Number</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Capacity</th>
        <th>Speed</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id="Memory1">
        <td>Memory1</td>
        <td>Shipping</td>
        <td>1GB</td>
        <td>1333MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory2">
        <td>Memory2</td>
        <td>Discontinued</td>
        <td>1GB</td>
        <td>1000MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory3">
        <td>Memory3</td>
        <td>Shipping</td>
        <td>2GB</td>
        <td>1333MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory4">
        <td>Memory4</td>
        <td>Discontinued</td>
        <td>4GB</td>
        <td>1000MHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Memory5">
        <td>Memory5</td>
        <td>Shipping</td>
        <td>4GB</td>
        <td>1333MHz</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please post the jQuery you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was feeling a bit generous, the below code does the following

1. On checkbox change, map an array of selected values
2. Iterate selected values and find `td` containing said value
3. Show parent `tr` of selected value

   ```
   $(":checkbox").change(function() {
       var checkedValues = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() {
           return this.value;
       }).get();

       $("tbody tr").hide();
       for (var i = 0; i < checkedValues.length; i++) {
           $("tbody tr td:contains('" + checkedValues[i] + "')").parent("tr").show();
       }
   });
   ```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kXNAg/