# Filtering a table based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have the following table

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="OutputTable>
       
    <tbody id="tableData">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr id="filterRow">
        <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
 </table>
```

I want the checkbox in the footer to act like a filter; when it is checked i only want all rows with their checkbox to show. When the footer checkbox is not checked i want all rows to show.

I tried different things but i cant get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you checked this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776160/filter-certain-tr-based-on-checkbox-checked

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the kind of filtering I'm looking for! :)

Comment: Ok, you tell us what you are looking for then ?

Comment: What is #OutputTable id.Post your full code and explain the question properly as the question you have posted is not making any sense.

Comment: It's in the post. Each row contains a cell with a checkbox. Then i want another checkbox somewhere on the page to act like a filer. When the filter checkbox is checked, only the rows with checked checkboxes should show. If the filter checkbox is not checked, all rows should show.

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686377/jquery-show-hide-table-rows

Comment: This is not the kind of filtering I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example below for code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',
      'columnDefs': [
         {
            'targets': 0,
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function(data, type, row){
               if(type === 'display'){               
                  data = '<input type="checkbox" value="' + $('<div>').text(data).html() + '">';
               }
               
               return data;
            }
         }
      ],
      'order': [[1, 'asc']]
   });
  
   // Apply the search
   table.columns().every( function () {
      var that = this;        

      $( 'input[type="checkbox"]', this.footer() ).on( 'change', function (e) {
         var values = '';
    
         if(this.checked){
            $.each(table.column(0).$('input:checked'), function(index, el){
               var value = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(el.value);
               values += ((values !== '') ? '|' : '') + value;
            });               
               
            values = '^(' + values + ')$';
         }
            
         that.search(values, true, false).draw();
      });
   });
    
   // Handle checkbox change event to exclude the row if column is being filtered
   $('#example').on( 'change', 'tbody input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {    
      var td = $(this).closest('td');
      var col = table.cell(td).index().column;
       
      // If column is being filtered
      if(table.column(col).search() !== ''){
         // Trigger change event to exclude the row
         $( 'input[type="checkbox"]', table.column(col).footer()).trigger('change');
      }
   });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/dt/dt-1.10.10,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/dt/dt-1.10.10,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th><input type="checkbox"></th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Age</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below code helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#filterRow input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked"))
     {
       $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
       if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(this).parent().parent().show();
       else
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
       });

     }
     else
     {
       $("input[type=checkbox]").parent().parent().show();
     }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="OutputTable">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
      <td>Sometext</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr id="filterRow">
        <th><input type="checkbox"> </th>
        <th>Filter</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This ALMOST works exactly as i wanted! I use DataTables which means that my table is pagified. This works perfectly on individual pages, but not on the entire table including all pages. Is this possible to fix with this solution?

Comment: Please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not. It looks like you have a table with multiple pages. Each page may contains some of the rows having check box checked. When you click on filter check box you need to show all the rows which have check box checked. But if this is the requirement then you need to handle it differently. Just make an ajax call on clicking on filter check box. Bring data table from server in such a way that the data table contains only checked rows. When you uncheck a filter check box then again make ajax call and bring all rows and display.